# Form serialize() не работает в IE9

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

Есть такая разметка:

```
<form method="POST" id="add_rule_form"></form>
<table class="list issues" style="margin-top: 20px">
   <tbody id="table_notification_body">
       <tr id="new_rule_row" class="hascontextmenu odd "><td class="number"><input type="text" name="sequence" id="sequence" value="613" form="add_rule_form" onkeyup="localStorage.setItem('sequence_is_change', 1);"></td><td class="project"><span class="jump-box-arrow"></span><select name="project_quick_jump_box" id="project_quick_jump_box" form="add_rule_form"><option value="-1">Выбрать проект...</option></tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

С помощью JQuery пытаюсь сериализовать форму:

```
var data = $("#add_rule_form").serialize().split("&");
```

В итоге в `data` находится только это:

```
[
  0: "",
  length: 1
]
```

Причем такое происходит только на IE9, в остальных браузерах все нормально. Как можно исправить данную проблему?

Comment: так у тебя же форма закрыта раньше блока table Оо. Добавь контент внутрь формы. Странно что в других браузерах все нормально

Comment: @alexoander, так у элементов же стоит атрибут `form`, но насколько я понял он не поддерживается в IE

Comment: это как бы не особо важно, т.к. ты используешь селектор JQuery. $("#add_rule_form"), который вернет пустую форму и сериализовать в ней нечего. В новых бразуерах возможно оно запихнет контент с атрибутами form внутрь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я и описал в комментарии, ошибка возможна в том, что форма закрыта раньше, чем начинается сам контент формы.

`$("#add_rule_form")` селектор вернет пустую форму, и сериализация вполне верно возвращает результат 0, т.к. нечего проверять. Возможно в других браузерах есть какая-либо логика, которая присваивает контент с атрибутами `form` внутрь самой формы, но IE на такое не способен.

Решение довольно простое - запихнуть контент внутрь формы и проверить, что селектор вернет объект с `childElement.length != 0`